# Jstatd Remote profiler with jvisualvm

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm, jstatd

I am trying to profile my web application on my local windows 7 PC `visualVM`.

I created a `jstatd.all.policy` file with below code under java's bin directory on my `CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 server`

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

and tried starting jstatd` with below command

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -p 1099
```

but when I try profiling on my local PC, I didn't see any process under `jvisualvm` remote host but just node

i also tried for a test purpose by starting `jstatd` with same approach on my `window server R2 2008` PC and tried to profile with `Windows 7 visualVM` but still no result just a node with no process but i tried on same windows server pc by adding the remote host for same pc than it shows running processes.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Start **jstatd** by this command:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname={Your Ip address}
```

Comment: An additional note is to make sure you start _VisualVM_ as a regular user i.e. do **NOT** use `psexec -s`.  The feature in VisualVM is also called _Add jstatd Connection_ in the right-click menu on _Local_.